# Click on control cause unwanted JS call

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an unexpected behavior of two JS which get called when I click on a control.
These JS are supposed to be called only when the button in the Tree list is clicked under specific conditions.

Right now the JS "message alert" is called even if a click on any of the node of the tree list when the conditions apply.

The other JS, which open a window, also opens when a node of the tree list is clicked, but after having opened and closed it at least one time.

```
 protected void RadTreeList1_ItemCommand(object sender, TreeListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string idMessage = "";
    if (e.CommandName == "Select")
    {
        if (e.Item is TreeListDataItem)
        {
            TreeListDataItem item = e.Item as TreeListDataItem;
           idMessage = item.GetDataKeyValue("MessageID").ToString();
        }
    }
    addMessage(idMessage);
}
private void addMessage(string idMessage)
{
    if (Label1.Text =="" || Label1.Text==null )
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", "alert('You shall be logged-in to post and replay to messages');", true);
    }
    else
    {   
        {
            Session["fatherMessageID"] = idMessage;
            string script = "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>Sys.Application.add_load(ShowWindow);</script>";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showWindow", script); 
        }
    }
}
```

Function which opens the window:

```
function ShowWindow() {
        var oWnd = window.radopen('Window1.aspx', 'window1');
    }
```

Function which close the window from inside the window:

```
function GetRadWindow() {
        var oWnd = null;
        if (window.radWindow) oWnd = window.radWindow;
        else if (window.frameElement.radWindow) oWnd = window.frameElement.radWindow;
        return oWnd;
    }
    function CloseWindow() {
        var oWnd = GetRadWindow();
        oWnd.close()
    }
```

Function which calls the CloseWindow inside the window page:

```
 finally
        {  
            string script = "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>Sys.Application.add_load(CloseWindow);</script>";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CloseWindow", script); 

        }
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: may be you need to place addMessage(idMessage); inside if (e.Item is TreeListDataItem) condition

Comment: @Sandeep, thanks for you hint. This has solved the unwanted call on the message alert. But I still have the problem on the window which opens as above described.

Comment: not sure whether window.radopen('Window1.aspx', 'window1') is correct or not. if you are using RadWindow then showwindow function should be something like this var oWnd = window.radopen(null, "[RadWindowID]");

Comment: @Sandeep, please post your comments as answer and I will accept it. Thanks for the hints, I sorted out both issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alert Issue:** 
you need to place addMessage(idMessage); inside if (e.Item is TreeListDataItem) condition

**Dialog Issue:** 
not sure whether window.radopen('Window1.aspx', 'window1') is correct or not. if you are using RadWindow then showwindow function should be something like this var oWnd = window.radopen(null, "[RadWindowID]");